# Excel trim prefix zero that is created using Perl script

Tags: perl

I have created a script using Perl, that will convert the CSV file to Excel. But excel trim the first zeros from the filed. But zero are mandatory in output file. Below is the code I did

```
my $workbook  =  Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("$pipeline_project_temp\\$without_extension.xls");

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

$outfilename = "$without_extension.xls";
# Create a new CSV parsing object
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;

# Row and column are zero indexed
my $row = 0;

my $line_content = "";
while (<CSVFILE>) {
    $line_content = $_;
    $line_content !~ s/[^[:ascii:]]//g;
    if ($csv->parse($line_content)) {
        my @Fld = $csv->fields;

        my $col = 0;
        foreach my $token (@Fld) {
            $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
            $col++;
        }
        $row++;
    }
    else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Text::CSV_XS parse() failed on argument: ", $err, "\n";
    }
}
```

044444 will conver to to 44444.  Can I use some logic that I can convert INT to String ?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, Excel::Writer::XLSX is the newer iteration of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and outputs in the OOXML format.  Its output is more compact, as a side benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[keep_leading_zeros](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel#keep_leading_zeros) is documented.